# Can I Sync Pocket Access on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile-5.0, activesync, xp-mode

I have to sync a Pocket Access database with Access on the PC.  WMDC won't let me do that and ActiveSync won't run on Vista so I can't do it.  Works great on XP.

Windows 7 has an XP mode.  It runs XP in a virtual machine or something like that.

Question: Can I Sync Pocket Access on Windows Mobile 5.0 with Access on Windows 7 if I'm running in XP mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can.

It does run in a VM and that VM can access the USB ports.

1. Open XP mode and log in.  Make sure
   ActiveSync is running in XP.
2. Attach the device to your physical
   machine.
3. In XP mode, choose 'USB' in the top
   menu.  You'll see a connected device
   that won't necessarily be identified
   properly but you'll be able to tell
   which is it.

Works great.